# Bouncy Castle Upgrade issue 1.60 and 1.6.1 or higher

Tags: java, bouncycastle

We have an issue when upgrading `bcprov-jdk15on-160.jar` and `bctls-jdk15on-160.jar` to `bcprov-jdk15on-161.jar` and `bctls-jdk15on-161.jar` or higher versions

> java.lang.InternalError: unable to open random source at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$URLSeededSecureRandom$1.run(DRBG.java:294)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$URLSeededSecureRandom$1.run(DRBG.java:285)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$URLSeededSecureRandom.(DRBG.java:284)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.createCoreSecureRandom(DRBG.java:131)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.createInitialEntropySource(DRBG.java:115)
>   at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.access$400(DRBG.java:29)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$HybridSecureRandom.(DRBG.java:357)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.createBaseRandom(DRBG.java:179)
>   at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.access$100(DRBG.java:29)
>   at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$Default.(DRBG.java:193)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method) at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513) at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:357) at
>   java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310) at
>   java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1221) at
>   sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:220) at
>   sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:147) at
>   java.security.SecureRandom.getInstance(SecureRandom.java:254) at
>   java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:176) at
>   java.security.SecureRandom.(SecureRandom.java:133)

when enabled debug log. It is an error about \dev\urandom

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: \dev\urandom (The system cannot find
>   the path specified) at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method) at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:120) at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.(FileInputStream.java:79) at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:70)
>   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:161)
>   at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010) at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$URLSeededSecureRandom$1.run(DRBG.java:290)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$URLSeededSecureRandom$1.run(DRBG.java:1)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$URLSeededSecureRandom.(DRBG.java:284)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.createCoreSecureRandom(DRBG.java:131)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.createInitialEntropySource(DRBG.java:115)
>   at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.access$2(DRBG.java:77)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$HybridSecureRandom.(DRBG.java:358)
>   at
>   org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.createBaseRandom(DRBG.java:179)
>   at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG.access$0(DRBG.java:162)
>   at org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.drbg.DRBG$Default.(DRBG.java:193)

There is no issue when using the 160 version.

I am using Java 6 32 bit on Windows 10 64 bit.

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks.

```
public class BCUpgradeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider(), 1);
            Security.insertProviderAt(new BouncyCastleProvider(), 1);
            KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH");
            System.out.println(ka.getProvider().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this code to your program's startup:

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Properties;

try {
    Field propsField = Security.class.getDeclaredField("props");
    propsField.setAccessible(true);
    Properties props = (Properties) propsField.get(null);
    props.remove("securerandom.source");
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.err.println("Unable to modify java.lang.Security properties!");
    System.err.println("BouncyCastle DRBG may fail.");
}
```

Which should at least give you a different error message. Note that I haven't actually tested this; it's based on the following code analysis.

The `FileNotFoundException` you posted is thrown from an [`URLSeededSecureRandom`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/e2e7fecc21ef2719c3b5371bb8b04325c1fd2905/prov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/drbg/DRBG.java#L275) instance constructed with an `URL` of `file:/dev/random`. Of course, since you're on Windows, `/dev/random` does not exist and `url.openStream()` fails. (The resulting `FileNotFoundException` is caught and rethrown as an [`InternalError`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/InternalError.html), of all things; why BouncyCastle uses an `Error` class designed to "indicate some unexpected internal error has occurred in the Java Virtual Machine", I have no idea.)

But the `file:/dev/random` part actually isn't hardcoded. It comes from [`DRBG.createCoreSecureRandom()`](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/e2e7fecc21ef2719c3b5371bb8b04325c1fd2905/prov/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/jcajce/provider/drbg/DRBG.java#L119):

```java
private static SecureRandom createCoreSecureRandom()
{
    if (Security.getProperty("securerandom.source") == null)
    {
        return new CoreSecureRandom(findSource());
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            String source = Security.getProperty("securerandom.source");

            return new URLSeededSecureRandom(new URL(source));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return new SecureRandom();  // we're desperate, it's worth a try.
        }
    }
}
```

Essentially it calls `Security.getProperty("securerandom.source")`, and if it's not `null`, it uses the property to construct a `URLSeededSecureRandom`. For some reason, on your system `securerandom.source` must be something like `file:/dev/random` even though it's a Windows JVM, so BouncyCastle tries to make a CSPRNG out of that.

You need to set `securerandom.source` to `null` so that `DRBG.createCoreSecureRandom()` takes the other code path. Unfortunately, you can't simply use `Security.setProperty("securerandom.source", null)` because [`Security`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Security.html)'s property list is a [`Properties`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Properties.html) instance backed by a `ConcurrentHashMap` which doesn't allow `null` values. And `Security` doesn't give you access to the underlying `Properties` instance so that you can call `remove()` on it. So you must use the reflection hackery posted at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks **MultiplyByZer0** your code resolved the issue about

> java.lang.InternalError: unable to open random source

Still having another issue with `bcprov-jdk15on-162.jar` and `bctls-jdk15on-162.jar`

The error trace:

> java.lang.SecurityException: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC
>   at javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA13*..) at
>   javax.crypto.KeyAgreement.getInstance(DashoA13*..) at
>   bc.test.BCUpgradeTest.main(BCUpgradeTest.java:46) Caused by:
>   java.util.jar.JarException: Cannot parse
>   file:/D:/Eclipse/workspace/BCTestProject/libs/bcprov-jdk15on-162.jar
>   at javax.crypto.SunJCE_c.a(DashoA13*..) at
>   javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.b(DashoA13*..) at
>   javax.crypto.SunJCE_b.a(DashoA13*..)

the updated test program

```
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.crypto.KeyAgreement;

import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.bouncycastle.jsse.provider.BouncyCastleJsseProvider;

public class BCUpgradeTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Field propsField = Security.class.getDeclaredField("props");
            propsField.setAccessible(true);
            Properties props = (Properties) propsField.get(null);
            props.remove("securerandom.source");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to modify java.lang.Security properties!");
            System.err.println("BouncyCastle DRBG may fail.");
        }

        try {
            BouncyCastleJsseProvider jsseProvider = new BouncyCastleJsseProvider();
            int jssePos = Security.insertProviderAt(jsseProvider, 1);
            BouncyCastleProvider castleProvider = new BouncyCastleProvider();
            int bcPos = Security.insertProviderAt(castleProvider, 1);

            System.out.println("jssePos = " + jssePos);
            System.out.println("bcPos = " + bcPos);

            System.out.println(castleProvider.getVersion());
            System.out.println(BCUpgradeTest.class.getClassLoader().getResource("org/bouncycastle/LICENSE.class"));

            Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
            for (int i = 0; i < providers.length; i++) {
                System.out.println("name : " + providers[i].getName() + "; version = " + providers[i].getVersion());
            }

            KeyAgreement ka = KeyAgreement.getInstance("ECDH", castleProvider);
            System.out.println(ka.getProvider().getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Below is the output from Console

```
jssePos = 1
bcPos = 1
1.62
jar:file:/D:/Eclipse/workspace/BCTestProject/libs/bcprov-jdk15on-162.jar!/org/bouncycastle/LICENSE.class
name : BC; version = 1.62
name : BCJSSE; version = 1.0009
name : SUN; version = 1.6
name : SunRsaSign; version = 1.5
name : SunJSSE; version = 1.6
name : SunJCE; version = 1.6
name : SunJGSS; version = 1.0
name : SunSASL; version = 1.5
name : XMLDSig; version = 1.0
name : SunPCSC; version = 1.6
name : SunMSCAPI; version = 1.6
```

Note that I use the official jar files without any modification.

Comment: I think this is a possible duplicate of a similar question I have answered:

Here is how I solved the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59845413/497378